# Error. Object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm compiling a scala application and I found the error typed in the title.

Scala version: scala 2.11.8
Spark version: spark 1.6.1
Intellij: 2016 1.3

I follow this example http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html and I change my sbt file like this:

name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

It is possible there is not compatibility between scala and spark versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the compatibility between scala and spark versions . But in my project we are using  scala 2.10 and spark 1.6 . we are using this from last 1 year in production as well .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make use of the compatible scala and spark version.[image: Please see the below screeshot for reference]